# Power Management Settings Changes Not Taking Effect

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04, power-management, hibernate

Since upgrading to 20.04 (xubuntu flavor) my desktop system will enter hibernation while idle for a while.  I have gone into the settings for the screen saver and power management trying to adjust the values, but the changes are not being saved, nor do they seem to effect change.  I'm getting the feeling that I currently have 2 sets of settings and or processes on this computer since the update.  This has been a 6 month release cycle install for almost 10 years now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since I updated from xubuntu 18.10 to 20.04 (full reinstall then copy/past my home folder)

I noted that in my case when I change Power Management settings in the UI, they are not reset if I close the setting UI or even reboot my computer. The values I have set are still there but seem to have no effect.

I also tried to run Power Management in debug mode and it correctly logs all setting changes.

The problem only impact *Display* tab settings (time before suspend/shutdown, screen luminosity reduction, etc). Other Power Management settings (such as locking on suspend, key settings, etc) work fine.

As a temporary workaround I use the "presentation mode" of the power managment widget to inhibit hibernation.